# Get User inside a SQLFilter in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I’m starting with Symfony and I want to make a multi tenant application.

I want to automatically filter in my SQL queries the content according to the company of belonging of the connected user, every time a table has a link with my company table.

I found the way to create filters but I can not find a way to retrieve in this filter the information about the company of the connected user.

I use FOSuser I override it with my own User class.

my config.yml

```
#app\config\config.yml

    doctrine:
        dbal:
           ...
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: true
            filters:
                company:
                    class: 'Acme\CompanyBundle\Repository\Filters\CompanyFilter'
                    enabled: true
```

my Filter

```
<?php
#src\Acme\CompanyBundle\Repository\Filters\CompanyFilter.php

namespace Acme\CompanyBundle\Repository\Filters;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetaData;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserEntity;
use Acme\CompanyBundle\Entity\CompanyEntity;

class CompanyFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        if ($targetEntity->hasAssociation("company")) {

            // here how to get the connected user ???

            $company = $user->getCompany();
            $idCompany = $company->getId();
            return $targetTableAlias . ".company_id = '".$idCompany."'";


        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

in advance thank you for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set an onKernelRequest listener, pass it the token storage service, so it defines your user as parameter of your SQLFilter.

So in your services.yml add :

```
services:
    on_request_listener:
        class: Acme\CompanyBundle\EventListener\OnRequestListener
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@security.token_storage"]
        tags:
            -
                name: kernel.event_listener
                event: kernel.request
                method: onKernelRequest
```

Create the listener :

```
class OnRequestListener
{
    protected $em;
    protected $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct($em, $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if($this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
            $filter = $this->em->getFilters()->enable('company');
            $filter->setParameter('user', $user);
        }
    }
}
```

Then at last your SQLFilter :

```
<?php
#src\Acme\CompanyBundle\Repository\Filters\CompanyFilter.php

namespace Acme\CompanyBundle\Repository\Filters;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetaData;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserEntity;
use Acme\CompanyBundle\Entity\CompanyEntity;

class CompanyFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        if ($targetEntity->hasAssociation("company") && $this->hasParameter('user')) {

            $user = $this->getParameter('user');

            $company = $user->getCompany();
            $idCompany = $company->getId();
            return $targetTableAlias . ".company_id = '".$idCompany."'";


        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have an error in the onKernelRequest function :
    `Call to a member function getUser() on null`

Comment: Indeed, I added a condition, there is of course cases where there is no token set.

Comment: I forgot to use `use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface; `
Now that is in the SQLFilter that I have an error, it dont't know `getParameter('user')`

Comment: Updated the answer, my bad. If we don't always set the user parameter, we need to set the SQL filter (depending on it) only when said user parameter is set.

Comment: thank you, I understood my mistake, I had another instantiated filter and it was a problem for me, it works for me now.

Comment: I wouldn't add the user to the filter by `$filter->setParameter('user', $user)` because `setParameter` expects a string (although not verified, but maybe in the future). I'd rather add an additional `setUser` method to the `CompanyFilter` which stores the user.